# implementation of operator overload (+=) in ruby

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

how to implement operator overloading (operator += )for two one-dimensional arrays? for b+=a in method  def +@ ??? end

```
    class Vector
def initialize
    @vector = Array.new
  end

  def set_vector=(vector)
    @vector = vector
  end

  def get_vector
    @vector
  end

  def +@
    ?????
  end  
end

a = Vector.new 
a.set_vector = [1,3,4,5]
print a.get_vector
b = Vector.new
b.set_vector = [1,2]
print b.get_vector
a.get_vector += b.get_vector
puts "\n a new"
puts a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a more Ruby way of doing this that fixes the issue:

```
class Vector
  attr_accessor :vector

  def initialize(*values)
    @vector = values
  end

  def [](i)
    @vector[i]
  end

  def +(vector)
    Vector.new(
      *@vector.map.with_index do |v, i|
        v + vector[i].to_i
      end
    )
  end
end
```

Note that `+` is just a regular method, there's no `+@` method involved here, that's the unary `+` as in `r = +v`, but you want to return a new object so you can chain it, as in `a + b + c`, and never modify the original.

`+=` creates a new object and does the assignment, as in `x = x + 1`.

In practice:

```
v = Vector.new(1,2)

r = v + Vector.new(2,3)

# => #<Vector:0x00007fc6678955a0 @vector=[3, 5]>
```

Comment: Note that with the current solution `Vector.new(1, 2) + Vector.new(3, 4, 5) #=> #<Vector @vector=[4, 6]>`. Leaving out the `5` since you'd call `@vector.map` on the smallest one.

Comment: I'd use something like `small, large = [self, other].map(&:vector).sort_by(&:size)` then `Vector.new(*large.zip(small).map { |values| values.sum(&:to_i) })`